# Translate a taxonomy term in the exposed filter select options

Tags: views, 8, i18n-l10n

I'm using Drupal 8 with Better Exposed Filters and for some reason the select options in the exposed filters (which are taxonomy terms) are refusing to appear translated, despite the fact that the rendering language is set to "Interface text language selected for page."

I'm using Better Exposed Filters, but this behavior also occurs when it's not used.

How can I make them appear translated?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. It's obvious from your description it's not to do with BEF. Are you sure your terms are translated? Are you visiting your Views page with lang prefix or whichever method you have? Is your language negotiation properly configured?

Comment: Terms are translated. Language negotiation properly configured. Using language path.